# Extract date from cell containing date and time

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I need to extract only the date from a cell that has both date and time.

Cell D3 reads:

> 12/9/2016  1:42:35 PM

There are two spaces between the date and time.

This is my attempt:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(D3,SEARCH("  ",D3)-1),D3)
```

This does give me only the date in the cell HOWEVER when I try to use it elsewhere it copies the original contents of D3 which  still includes the time..

It seems maybe this formula changes the formatting, but not the actual contents, since I still can't copy only the date without the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is formatted as a date you can extract like this:

```
=TEXT(D3,"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Comment: Awesome - that was easier than I thought. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help. Please close the question by accepting the answer (the tick mark to the left of the answer).